# Error, too many connections to mysql using PDO showed our db username and password?

Tags: mysql, pdo

At some point earlier on it appears there were too many sql connections and the following was echo'd to screen for whomever was looking:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message  'SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections' in /dir/file.php:21
Stack trace:
#0 /dir/file.php(21): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'the user', 'password')
```

As you can see, it printed the username and password.

I'm new to PDO form of connecting to db, and I got into it because people told me my regular mysql_connect form was insecure. However by default, when mysql_connect ever had too any connections it **never** printed the username and password to the screen.

What a disaster.

How do I stop PDO from doing this if it error's out??

I'm using:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $db, $user, $pass);
```

Comment: Did you ever happen to figure this one out?

Comment: I agree this is a problem and should be raised to the PDO team. Please vote for the concealment of the credentials upon error: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62184

Comment: Ok - will do. Although it seems bizarre there should even be a need to vote - its just ridiculous to default print username and password credentials in an error message!! And especially when apparently, at least my understanding of PDO is to make a more secure way of database access! Super fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your php.ini and set

```
display_errors = 0
```

If you don't have access to php.ini then at the top of your script(s) you need to add:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "0");
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

This will stop all errors from being outputted to the browser. Make sure you are still logging errors (via php.ini setting).

P.S. Do not toss away PDO

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal I completely agree, however you still want to disable the output to the browser as a precaution.

Comment: either will work - follow the convention in your php.ini file

Comment: If you disable errors, you will not see what is going on... (hide them away for production, though)

Answer (score 3):

PDO is not doing anything of the sort.

This is happening because you are not performing any exception handling, so the default PHP error handler is being invoked and showing your call stack, including function arguments.

Usually call stacks are a very good thing, so you *want* the error handler to work; you just need to use it properly.

- Place `try`/`catch` blocks in relevant places around code that can throw exceptions; at the very least, put a catch-all `try`/`catch` block around your code's top-level so that nothing seeps through.

PDO documentation, though, clearly states (in a red warning box) the big risk you take not properly catching PDO exceptions:

> If your application does not catch the exception thrown from the PDO constructor, the default action taken by the zend engine is to terminate the script and display a back trace. This back trace will likely reveal the full database connection details, including the username and password. It is your responsibility to catch this exception, either explicitly (via a catch statement) or implicitly via set_exception_handler().

(http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: That makes sense to a smarter version of myself. Now if I could work ou what a try/catch is. thanks for the pointer!!

Comment: @cosmicbdog: You definitely need to learn about exceptions before using a library that employs them!